# SVG HTML Not Drawing SVG Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Im creating an SVG pattern in HTML and the user will be able to change colour and size etc. But its not working.

I get an error regarding the body onload function. and then when appending the SVG Diagram to the svg placeholder that i have.

Here is the Script:

```
<script>
    var SVG = document.getElementById("svgArea");
    document.content.appendChild(SVG);

function drawCircle()
{


    var svgLink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var Centre = document.createElementNS(svgLink,"circle");

            Centre.setAttributeNodeNS(null,"id","Centre");
    Centre.setAttributeNodeNS(null,"cx",230);
            Centre.setAttributeNodeNS(null,"cy",0);
            Centre.setAttributeNodeNS(null,"r",75);
            Centre.setAttributeNodeNS(null,"fill","centreColour");



    document.getElementById("svgArea").appendChild(Centre);


    var group = document.getElementById("svgArea");
    group.setAttribute("transform","translate(230,0)");

}
</script>
```

Then for the body tag i have the following:

```
<body onload="drawCircle()">
```

And for the contents of the page i have the following code:

```
<div class="content">
 <!-- SVG DIAGRAM -->

    <svg id="SVG" style="background:pink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="690" height"400">

    <g id="svgArea">
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Errors:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.content.appendChild')
global code (SVG.html, line 33)

[Error] TypeMismatchError: DOM Exception 17: The type of an object was incompatible with the     expected type of the parameter associated to the object.
drawCircle (SVG.html, line 57)
onload (SVG.html, line 107)
```

Where and what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

This doesnt Work:

```
//Drawing Petals
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPetals; i++)
    {
        var svgLink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var flowerPettle = document.createElementNS(svgLink,"ellipse");


        flowerPettle.setAttributeNS(null,"id","flowerPettle");
        flowerPettle.setAttributeNS(null,"ry", 230);
        flowerPettle.setAttributeNS(null,"rx",0)
        flowerPettle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",petalColour);

        var rotate = "rotate(" + (i*(360 / numberOfPetals)) + " " + 300 + "," + 30 + ")";

        flowerPettle.setAttribute("transform",rotate);


        document.getElementById("FlowerArea").appendChild(flowerPettle);

    }
```

Comment: you're supposed to use `setAttributeNS()` instead `setAttributeNodeNS()`. Apart from that, your code looks fine assuming `svgArea` is the id of the element that is already in your markup

Comment: Ahh thanks Still get this error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.content.appendChild')
global codeSVG.html:34
SVG.html:61

Comment: With `document.content` are you trying to select the `div` with `content` class?

Comment: Ok the document.content im trying to access a <g tag in the SVG area. The circle works now ive sorted that out. 

Could you have a look to see whats going on in the edited and added code above? Why doesnt these patterns show?

Comment: where is `FlowerArea` in your markup?

Comment: This is the SVGArea this is from my program now

Comment: Sorted that now Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.  One is the `createAttributeNode()` calls.  Another is the `document.content` reference. Plus there are things like the strange colour value "centreColour".

I've put together a working fiddle.  Hopefully it helps you get things working in your code.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GtbFu/1/)